# Very easy question about the characteristic function

Tags: real-analysis

I want to show that if $\{ A_n \} $ are pairwise disjoint , then

$$ 1_{\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n } = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1_{A_n} $$

#### My attempt:

Let $f(x) = \sum 1_{A_n} $. Then we know that $f(x) = 1$ if $x$ lies in at least one of the $A_n \subset \bigcup A_n$ and $f$ is $0$ otherwise. And so $f(x) = 1_{\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n } $.

Is this a valid argument? Also, it seems as I can drop the requirement that the $A_n's$ are pairwise disjoint. Do I need it ?

Comment: You do need it. Imagine the worst possible scenario: all $A_n$'s are equal (and non-empty), so that $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n = A_1$. Then, for $x\in A_1$, you have $1_{\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n }(x) = 1$, but $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1_{A_n}(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 1 = \infty$.